# Firebase hosting: Rewrite to function not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

My `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "dev",
      "public": "public",
      "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "function": "ssr",
          "region": "europe-west1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
}
```

I'm trying to rewrite any traffic to my `ssr` function. Whenever I try to access my website, I get a 404 with the messages `Error: Page not found` and `The requested URL was not found on this server.`

I have successfully deployed the `ssr` function. The function works if I access its URL directly. But for some reason, firebase rewriting is just not working.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does your Cloud Function URL contain `run.app` or `cloudfunctions.net`?

Comment: @samthecodingman cloudfunctions.net, does that make a difference?

Comment: The newest version of Cloud Functions for Firebase is built on top of Cloud Run, so it could have been that your function was hosted using it, but that doesn't seem to apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was deploying my functions and hosting separately, e.g.  `firebase deploy --only functions`. When I tried deploying them simultaneously, i.e. by just running `firebase deploy` it worked.